# ParamQuery Pasting Issues In Visualforce Page

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

I have two custom objects in Salesforce: an analysis and analysis components. Components are always children of 1 analysis. I build these to mimic a tool our sales team has in Excel, think of components as rows in an Excel sheet and an analysis as the workbook.

I'm trying to create way to edit all the components of an analysis via a spreadsheet in Salesforce. I did some digging and found [Making A Spreadsheet with Visualforce and Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Making_A_Spreadsheet_On_Force.com) and have adapted the linked package to my needs. I also found [this cut-copy demo](https://paramquery.com/pro/demos/copy_paste) which properly handles pasting the way I require it to do.

I've attempted to adjust mine to mimic this but when I copy and Excel column and paste it into my grid it pastes into one cell rather than into the column. I don't have any training in JavaScript which is probably one the biggest issue, but I wasn't sure if this could be an issue with running the script within `apex:page` tags or something of this nature. Or perhaps it has to do with the `customGridKey`

Here is some of the page:

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Consumable Analysis: </td>
            <td class="value">
                <apex:selectList styleClass="fiscal-year" id="analysis" value="{!chosenAnalysis}" size="1">
                    <apex:selectOption value="{!consumableAnalyses}"/>
                </apex:selectList>            
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Save" id="save-records" />
</apex:form>
<div id="grid-array" style="margin:10px 0;"></div>
<div id="grid-menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="insert">Insert</li>
        <li id="delete">Delete</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is some of the JavaScript:

```
    var GridObj;
var $grid;
var pqSearch;
var SummaryData={};
var DeleteArray=[];
$(function () {
    attachSaveRecordListener();
    //right click listeners
    $('#grid-menu').on("click", function() {
        $('#grid-menu').hide();
    });
    $(document).on("click", function() {
        $('#grid-menu').hide();
    });
    $('#delete').on("click", function() {
        $('#grid-menu').hide();
        deleteRow();
    });
    $('#insert').on("click", function() {
        $('#grid-menu').hide();
        insertRow();
    });

    GridObj = { width: 1300, height: 500, title: "Consumable Component Sheet", resizable:true, electionModel: { type: 'row' }, selectionModel: { column:true }, virtualX: true, virtualY: true
        };


    gridDropdownCallback(function(){
        getGridData();
    });
});
function gridDropdownCallback(callback){
    GridObj.colModel = [
        { title: "Id", dataType: "string", hidden: true },    //Id
    { title: "Size", width: 40, dataType: "integer", className:'planned-data'},
    { title: "Pipettes", width: 40, dataType: "integer", className:'real-data'},
    { title: "Data Points", width: 40, dataType: "integer", className:'balance-data'},
    {title:"Analysis", dataType: "string", hidden:true},
    {title: "RecordType", dataType: "string", hidden:true}
        ];    

    if(callback) callback();
}
    function getGridData(){
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.ConAnaSpreadsheetController.queryComponents}',
        $('.fiscal-year').val(),
        function(result){
            var gridData = [];
            $(result).each(function (i) {
                gridData.push(createArrayElement(this));
            }); //end Each
            gridCallback(gridData);
        }//end callback function
    );   //end vf 
}//end function getGridData
    function gridCallback(gridData){
    GridObj.dataModel = { data: gridData};    //rPP: 15, rPPOptions: [10, 15, 20], paging: "local"         
    $grid = $("#grid-array").pqGrid(GridObj);
    $grid.on("pqgridcelleditkeydown", customGridKey);
    $grid.on("keydown", function (evt) {
        var keyCode = evt.keyCode;
        if (keyCode == 38 || keyCode == 40 || keyCode == 37 || keyCode == 39) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
    var customGridKey = function(evt, ui){
    var keyCode = evt.keyCode,
        rowIndxPage = ui.rowIndxPage,
        colIndx = ui.colIndx;
    var DM = $grid.pqGrid("option", "dataModel");
    var gridData = DM.data;

    if (keyCode == 40 || keyCode == 38 || keyCode == 37 || keyCode == 39) {
        $grid.pqGrid("saveEditCell");
    }


    if(keyCode == 37 && colIndx > 0){
        colIndx--;
        $grid.pqGrid("editCell", {rowIndxPage: rowIndxPage, colIndx: colIndx});
        evt.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    if(keyCode == 39 && colIndx < gridData[0].length - 1){
        colIndx++;
        $grid.pqGrid("editCell", {rowIndxPage: rowIndxPage, colIndx: colIndx});
        evt.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    if (keyCode == 40) {
        if (rowIndxPage >= gridData.length - 1) {
            var dt = ui.$cell.text();
        //    if (dt.length > 0) {
                var row = createArrayElement(new Consumable_Analysis_Component__c({
                    }));

                gridData.push(row);
                $grid.pqGrid("refreshDataAndView");
        //    }
        }
        if (rowIndxPage < gridData.length - 1) {
            rowIndxPage++;
            $grid.pqGrid("setSelection", null);
            $grid.pqGrid("setSelection", { rowIndx: rowIndxPage });
            $grid.pqGrid("editCell", { rowIndxPage: rowIndxPage, colIndx: colIndx });
            evt.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }else if (keyCode == 38 && rowIndxPage > 0) {
        rowIndxPage--;
        $grid.pqGrid("setSelection", null);
        $grid.pqGrid("setSelection", { rowIndx: rowIndxPage });
        $grid.pqGrid("editCell", { rowIndxPage: rowIndxPage, colIndx: colIndx });
        evt.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded paramQuery again to make sure I had the latest version, and then using [this example](https://paramquery.com/demos/copy_paste) I changed the object model as such:

```
GridObj = { width: "100%", title: "Consumable Component Sheet", resizable:true, 
            showBottom: false, editModel: {clicksToEdit: 2}, numberCell: {show:false}, 
            scrollModel: {autoFit: true}};
```